# Yarn install dead with JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: yarnpkg

I used to have a fully functional yarn installation, everything working fine with my corporate proxy. But after 5 weeks I left it rotting, all of a sudden it is not working anymore.

When I run a simple `yarn install`, it stays there for some 2 minutes, then dies. Its output:

```
yarn install v1.22.4

<--- Last few GCs --->

[1464:0000000000441F90]   104273 ms: Scavenge 1396.5 (1425.7) -> 1395.7 (1426.2) MB, 4.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.147, current mu = 0.083) allocation failure
[1464:0000000000441F90]   104362 ms: Scavenge 1396.9 (1426.2) -> 1396.2 (1427.2) MB, 5.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.147, current mu = 0.083) allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 000000013F3FDD8A v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+4506
 2: 000000013F3D8886 node::MakeCallback+4534
 3: 000000013F3D9200 node_module_register+2032
 4: 000000013F6F30DE v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846
 5: 000000013F6F300F v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+639
 6: 000000013F8D9804 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+9620
 7: 000000013F8D07E6 v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+24550
 8: 000000013F8CEE3C v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+17980
 9: 000000013F8D4D87 v8::internal::Heap::CreateFillerObjectAt+1175
10: 000000013FC727D3 v8::internal::NativesCollection<0>::GetScriptsSource+547
11: 000000013F35FD92 v8::internal::StackGuard::ArchiveSpacePerThread+52242
12: 000000013F360453 v8::internal::StackGuard::ArchiveSpacePerThread+53971
13: 000000013F441614 uv_dlerror+2452
14: 000000013F4423E8 uv_run+232
15: 000000013F3DFE7E node::NewContext+1390
16: 000000013F3E048B node::NewIsolate+603
17: 000000013F3E08E7 node::Start+823
18: 000000013F28F3CC node::MultiIsolatePlatform::MultiIsolatePlatform+604
19: 000000013FED863C v8::internal::compiler::OperationTyper::ToBoolean+129516
20: 0000000077B6556D BaseThreadInitThunk+13
21: 0000000077CC372D RtlUserThreadStart+29
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I found the culprit: at `.yarnrc` I had an invalid `cache-folder` setting:

```
cache-folder "L:\\yarn-cache"
```

So how can it be it used to work, but doesn't anymore?

When my corporation was setting up for social isolation, I decided to collect all the dependencies of all my active (and not so-active) projects in a pendrive, at the time at `L:`.

Now I'm accessing the desktop remotely, and the pendrive is not physically there.

I just wish that yarn could fail with a better message error.